# ubuntu server (14.04) freeze without any kernel message or log entries

Tags: linux, ubuntu, freeze

My ubuntu server (14.04) freezes regularly without any kernel message or log entries. Is there any option to isolate the problem?

Comment: Does the freeze happen on halt? I had a similar problem some time ago, I don't remember the cause, but it might be a clue where to search

Comment: i updated the mainboard und ipmi bios and now i test it again. when it fails then i try to update the lsi hba controller...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with update all bios and firmware the problem is done...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a hardware issue. One easy test you can do is a **memory check**. Reboot your computer and select it instead of booting *Ubuntu*. You may have to press *ESC* or *SHITF* key to reach the grub menu.

More information about the Memory Test at
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MemoryTest

If it happens to be a broken memory unit you can fix it easily replacing it.